# Jsoup- How to bind two un-nested div tags while scraping

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I am scraping a web page which is having separate div(s) for chapter name and Text. I need to keep record of which text belongs to what chapter. 
The method I am using for scraping is to select Chapter div tag and loop through all elements. Then Text div tag and loop through all text element.
There are less number of chapter tags than the text. Which means there can be multiple text within one chapter. 
How can I keep record of chapter vs text?
Please help!

My Jsoup Code

```
Elements chapInfos =doc.select("div.chapter");
for(Element chapInfo : chapInfos)
        {
            Elements tempChap= chapInfo.select("div.chapno");
            String ChapterNo = tempChap.text();
        }
        Elements Texts =doc.select("div.chapterText");
        for(Element text : Texts)
        {
            Elements tempText= text.select("div.EnglishText");
            String FinalText = tempText.text();
        }
```

Sample Webpage HTML

```
          <div class=chapter>
        <div class=chapno>(1)</div>
        </div>

        <div class=chapterText>
        <div class=EnglishText>Some Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class=chapterText>
        <div class=EnglishText>Some Other Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class=chapter>
        <div class=chapno>(2)</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying something like this:

`Elements elms =doc.select("div.chapter, div.chapterText");`

This would perhaps give a combined list of both types of divs that can be iterated over and anytime the class of internal div changes from `EnglishText` to  `chapno`, that would indicate the beginning of a new chapter.

Additionally, instead of matching the wrapper div, perhaps it could be a better idea to select the internal dive to avoid another level of matching like this:

`Elements elms =doc.select("div.chapter div, div.chapterText div");`